# laravel foreign key in migration return error

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-7

i have bad error when migration run

(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

and all fields of primary and foriegn key have same data primary key

both of them are unsignedBigInteger

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',100)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('rank');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });



 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->bigIncrements('id');
          $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

          $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->constrained()
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```